# How to get proper resolution from image loaded via drawable?

Tags: picasso

I am using Picasso in an Android application. The device I am testing with is a Samsung tablet (SM-T110), and is running Android version 4.2.2.

In several places, I load an image into an ImageView where the image is on the net and so I use a URL. This works great. Everything seems to be scaled fine.

I was setting an image with this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_list_image_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/gf_logo"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

and the image looked great.

Now I have:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_list_image_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

and

```
    Picasso
            .with(getBaseContext())
            .load(R.drawable.gf_logo)
            .resize(200, 200)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.happy_me)
            .error(R.drawable.happy_me)
            .into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_list_image_view));
```

in my activity class and the image looks to be the wrong resolution. It looks extremely fuzzy.

I have these versions of the image:

```
 app/src/main/res/drawable/gf_logo.png
 app/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/gf_logo.png
 app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/gf_logo.png
 app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/gf_logo.png
 app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/gf_logo.png
 app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/gf_logo.png
 app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/gf_logo.png
```

I was hoping that I could delete the "drawable/gf_logo.png" of the graphic and that Picasso would do the right thing and see which image to use for the resolution of the device, but that is not working.

Is there a way to get Picasso to use the image that has the resolution desired for the current device? Is there a way to get it to stop using the "drawable/gf_logo.png" version? If I try to delete that copy of the file, Android Studio complains that the Picasso call above is using the image and the deletion is not safe.

BTW, my gradle file starts with this:

```
 android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.xyzzy.xyzzy"
         minSdkVersion 14
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
```